# Make (Fluent) NHibernate Recreate only specific tables in a database

Tags: nhibernate

Is there a way to tell NHibernate to leave some tables alone?  I have the ASPNET Membership tables, and while I would like to be able to access them using NHibernate, I don't want SchemaExport to delete them and recreate them while recreating the other tables. (Goodness knows what may happen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `SchemaAction.None()`

More information here: http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/rodpaddock/archive/2010/06/29/using-fluent-nhibernate-with-legacy-databases.aspx